# Compiling GTK 3 apps on Debian

Tags: c, linux, debian, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to compile a GTK program on my Debian desktop. I installed libgtk-3-dev and all of that, but when I go to compile the program, I get this error:

```
$ gcc -o client client.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
client.c:6:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

All of the GTK headers actually seem to be in `/usr/include/gtk-3.0`, but even if I include `<gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>` I get errors, since the files inside include other GTK headers as if they were in a normal include path. Then if I compile with `-I/usr/include/gtk-3.0` I still get errors, this time about glib. Well, glib files are inside `/usr/include/glib-2.0` and it's the same problem as before. Finally, if I compile with `-I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0`, I this time get this error:

```
$ gcc -o client -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 client.c `pkg-config --cflags $ --libs glib-2.0`
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from client.c:6:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:35:10: fatal error: pango/pango.h: No such file or directory
   35 | #include <pango/pango.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Seems like any combination of compile flags I choose, I get some sort of error, all caused by Debian putting the headers in a non-standard subdirectory. This is not me messing with them, this is what apt installs for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking `pkg-config` for glib, you must ask `pkg-config` for the GTK+ library:

```
gcc -o client client.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

You can keep `glib-2.0` in the command line, but since GTK+ depends on glib, it's already included.